# Count occurrences of distinct values in 2 fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a MySQL query that will find distinct values in a particular field, count the number of occurrences of that value in 2 fields (1_user, 2_user) and then order the results by the count.

example db

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
|   id | 1_user    | 2_user    |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 |       2   | 1         | 
|    2 |       3   | 2         | 
|    3 |       8   | 7         | 
|    4 |       1   | 8         | 
|    5 |       2   | 8         |
|    6 |       3   | 8         |  
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

expected result

```
user       count
-----      -----
8          4
2          3
3          2
1          2
```

Comment: what do you want to get? distinct values in field 1_user and 2 user?

Comment: You should include `user = 7 & count = 1` in expected result. [See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/748d8/1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Query**

```
SELECT user, count(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT 1_user AS USER FROM test

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 2_user FROM test
) AS all_users
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY count DESC
```

**Explanation**

List all the users in the first column.

```
SELECT 1_user AS USER FROM test
```

Combine them with the users from the second column.

```
UNION ALL
SELECT 2_user FROM test
```

The trick here is the [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) which preserves duplicate values.

The rest is easy -- select the results you want from the subquery:

```
SELECT user, count(*) AS count
```

aggregate by user:

```
GROUP BY user
```

and prescribe the order:

```
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u, count(u) AS cnt 
FROM (
    SELECT 1_user AS u FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2_user AS u FROM table
) subquery 
GROUP BY u
ORDER by cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the 2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY 1_user

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY 2_user
```

Now combine them:

```
SELECT user, SUM(count) FROM
  ((SELECT 1_user as user FROM table)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT 2_user as user FROM table))
GROUP BY user, ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for since your expected result did not include `7`

```
select usr, count(usr) cnt from
(
   select user_1 usr from users
   union all
   select user_2 usr from users
) u
where u.usr in (select user_1 from users)
group by usr
order by count(u.usr) desc
```